# How to get the item view type of a SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter, properly?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, gridlayoutmanager

I use this code to give header items in a `RecyclerView` a span of two columns using a `GridLayoutManager`:

```java
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, items);
this.myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        switch (myAdapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
            case -1: // VIEW_TYPE_ITEM
                return 1;
            default: // VIEW_TYPE_HEADER
                return 2;
        }
    }
});
this.myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

This works, but it complains about my usage of `getItemViewType`, because it's deprecated. My adapter extends `SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`.

What should I use, instead?

(Also, I don't know about the enum that I should use in the switch statement, instead, but this is a different story.)

Comment: which version of recycler-view are you used? and in which version `getItemViewType` is deprecated?

Comment: @beigirad that's for asking. This entire question is a mistake, though. I'm editing a project that uses a `SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter` and I failed to recognize that it's not part of the Android library, so this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use recyclerview viewpool great way to do section recyclerview like google play its inbuilt functionality of recyclerview.

eg of section recyclerview -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyUjw6b5gXE

https://github.com/alghifari/RecycledViewPoolExample